# How do update MPAndroid chart with live values instead of arraylist?(Piechart)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have seen [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data) and I'm not quite able to understand. I need to implement real-time chart for a piechart. I have also looked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfLop_oLYU0&nohtml5=False).

```
 void update(int id, final int value) {
    value_all = value;
    String heart = String.valueOf(value);
    Log.d("Blink Hai", heart);
    if (textView != null && linearLayout != null) {
        textView.setText(heart);
        if (value > 50 && value < 60) {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else if (value > 60 && value < 90) {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (value > 90 && value < 100) {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
```

So right now, depending on the value being received, the background color of the screen is chaning and I've also put a textview to show the value. I need the chart to be updating this value in real-time. The update() function is called every 2 seconds from another class.